# Computing the average memory access time with following processor and cache performance

Tags: assembly, memory, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache

Consider the following processor and cache configurations

| Clock rate | 500MHz |
| --- | --- |
| Base CPI | 1 |
| L1 cache type | Separate Instruction and Data Cache |
| L1 cache write policy | Write-back |
| L1 cache hit time | 2ns |
| L1 miss penalty | 40ns(time to read from and write to main memory) |
| L1 instruction cache miss rate | 1% |
| L1 date cache miss rate | 5% |
| dirty data cache blocks | 40% of total data cache blocks |

(a) Compute the average memory access time(AMAT) for Instruction cache.

(b) Compute the average memory access time(AMAT) for data cache assuming load and store represent 20% of instructions.

*My answer*

(a) : 
According to the formula 
AMAT= hit time+miss rate* miss penalty 
AMAT= 2ns+0.01*40ns =2.4ns

(b) : 
According to the formula 
AMAT= hit time+miss rate* miss penalty 
AMAT= 2ns+0.05* 40ns*0.2 =2.4ns

Above answer is my opinion but I am not sure how to use cache configurations such as dirty data cache blocks and Clock rate. Are my answers right or am I missing something? Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1):

> 40ns(time to read from and write to main memory)

The use of the conjunction `and` in that text is awkward.  It could mean that 40ns = read + write-back, so 40ns for refilling a dirty cache line, but I think it is better to read that as "both" instead, so 40ns for read and also 40ns for write-back.  I would have written `or` there instead, to avoid the confusion between `and` in the sense of "both", or "as well", vs. in the sense of addition.

Your (a) looks right.

On (b):

1. The L1 data cache suffers a miss rate of 5% and in 40% of those cases, the miss has to write-back as well as read.  So, here, we need to distinguish between the read operations and the write-back operations, since all misses incur read time, while 40% will also incur write-back time.
2. I am not used to specifying an average access time for data (loads & stores), that includes instructions that don't access data.  However, that does make sense if at some point you want to combine the i & d-cache times to get an overall view of the AMAT per instruction.  So, going along that route, we need to apply the 20% to both hits and misses not just to misses.  I would compute the data cache performance without that 20% (i.e. given the instruction is a load or store: what is the AMAT), then factor that 20% in last to average that out over all instructions.

I don't see cycles or MHz involved in either question (a) or (b).